# How to pass Azure Data Factory Linked Service connection string as plain text?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Using Azure Data Factory, I am trying to create a linked service, connecting to a local sql server through a self-hosted Integration Runtime. I am using the Python Azure SDK.

Creation of the service succeeds, but I am not able to get the connection string right in my script. It's supposed to be the server name and database name in plain text, however, the [sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/python/api/azure-mgmt-datafactory/azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.SqlServerLinkedService?view=azure-python) only accepts the variable as a SecureString.

Here is some sample code:

```
from azure.mgmt.datafactory.models import (SecureString, SqlServerLinkedService)
from pprint import pprint
from azure_setup_automation.utils import print_item, pdir
from utils.config import get_config_sql, get_config_azure
from azure_setup_automation.utils import (get_azure_credentials)
from azure.mgmt.datafactory import DataFactoryManagementClient

conf = get_config_azure()
local_conf = get_config_sql()
credentials = get_azure_credentials(conf)
adf_client = DataFactoryManagementClient(credentials, conf.subscription_id)

connection_string_source = (
    f'Data Source={local_conf.server};'
    f'Initial Catalogue={local_conf.database};'
    'Integrated Security=False;'
)

ls_name_local_sql = '02_test_linked_service_local_sql'

ls_local_storage = SqlServerLinkedService(
    connection_string=SecureString(connection_string_source),
    connect_via={"referenceName": "IRTest1", "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"},
    user_name=local_conf.user_id,
    password=SecureString(local_conf.password)
)

ls_obj_local_sql = adf_client.linked_services.create_or_update(
    conf.resource_group_name,
    conf.azure_data_factory_name,
    ls_name_local_sql,
    properties = ls_local_storage
)

#print_item(ls_obj_local_sql)
#pdir(ls_obj_local_sql)
#print('-------------------------')
#print (ls_obj_local_sql.type)
#print (ls_obj_local_sql.serialize())

pprint (ls_obj_local_sql.as_dict())
```

This prints the following.

```
{'etag': 'XXXX-0000-0000-0000-5ba0fcb10000',
 'id': '/subscriptions/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/XXX/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/XXXX/linkedservices/02_test_linked_service_local_sql',
 'name': '02_test_linked_service_local_sql',
 'properties': {'connect_via': {'reference_name': 'IRTest1',
                                'type': 'IntegrationRuntimeReference'},
                'connection_string': {'type': 'SecureString',
                                      'value': '**********'},
                'encrypted_credential': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                'type': 'SqlServer',
                'user_name': 'XXXXX\\XXXXX'},
 'type': 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices'}
```

Here is a picture off of the ADF portal. Illustrating how the parameters show up asterisks, and how the connection fails: [Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaNWl.png)

Is there any way to pass these parameters in plain text without changing them manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was all thanks to a typo. Apparently the Americans have a different way of spelling for Catalogue:

```
f'Initial Catalog={local_conf.database};'
```

In the end, there is no need for the connection string to be in plain text, even if that's the way the portal interface presents it. I misunderstood what was going on, thinking that the error was about the sdk not being able to parse the SecureString.